# Matrix /injective

Tags: matrices, functions, vectors, matrix-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be given by the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1 & 1\\ 
3& 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$

1) I have to determine wheter $f$ is injective or not

I think that it can not be injective, because the rows are linearly dependent, third row= 3*(first row + second row)

2) If $f$ is not injective determine two vector $u,v$ such that $f(u)=f(v)$. I am stuck at point (2). How can I determine those vectors?

Comment: $f(u)=f(v)$ is the same as $f(u-v)=0$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: thank you, so I calculate the kernel of the matrix, and the vectors in the span of the kernel would be my $u$ and $v$?

Comment: You could take any vector in the kernel to be $u$ and $v$ to be $0$.